# Two Circles Can Have At Most One Common Chord? (IMO)

Tags: combinatorics, geometry

I am currently working to understand a combinatorics problem. Within the proof they state that "*Two circles can have at most one common chord* ..." and I do not understand why this is true. I've included a screenshot from my textbook.

[image]

The book then goes on to finish the proof. Now I can follow everything before the last paragraph, but have no idea why two circles can have at most one common chord (last full sentence of last paragraph).

**Question: Can you please provide some explanation for why two circles can have at most one common chord?**

Comment: Can you think of an example of two circles intersecting with say 2 common chords? That attempt should give you an answer.

Comment: Failure to dream up a counterexample is not normally considered a rigorous proof.

Comment: No.  But it can be an excellent start.

Comment: If two circles touch at a point, wouldn't a multitude of lines pass through that point and touch both circles?

Comment: Two circles * can* have more than one common chord but then they are the same circle (and have infinite chords in common)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two distinct circles will intersect in at most two points. If they intersect in two points, they have a single common chord, namely the line segment joining those two points. If they intersect in fewer than two points, they have no common chords.

Comment: Well, I think the OP was asking why they have at most two points in common...

Answer (score 19):

If two circles have two chords in common, then they must have at least three points in common.

A circle can be completely determined by three points, as there are three unknowns: the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the circle's center, and the radius.

If you want something more concrete: if you have two points $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$, then you know that the center of the circle must be equidistant from both; so, there is an infinite line of points to choose from for the center, and choosing the center completely determines the radius.

When you introduce a third point $(x_2,y_2)$, you can now note that the center of the circle must be equidistant from $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$, and must also be equidistant from $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. This gives two lines, whose intersection (if such exists) must be the center.  Assuming there is a good point for the center, the radius must be the common distance from this point to all three $(x_i,y_i)$ pairs.

Comment: I don't think the last point is complete. If the x & y of the circle's center are distinct unknowns, then three points actually have six knowns (the x & y of each). Thus one might expect that two points (four knowns) could uniquely identify a circle. As this is not the case, it doesn't immediately follow that bumping this to three points (six knowns) is sufficient to determine it. -- Contrast with a line segment, which has four unknowns (the x & y coordinates of the endpoints) but is determined either by two points (the end points) or can't be defined by an infinite number of internal points.

Comment: A data point is, in this case, a relationship between an $x$ coordinate and a $y$ coordinate, not the coordinates themselves.

The argument isn't perfect, but it is illustrative.

Comment: If you want something more concrete: if you have two points $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$, then you know that the center of the circle must be equidistant from both; so, there is an infinite line of points to choose from for the center; radius is then determined.  When you introduce a third point $(x_2,y_2)$, you can now note that the center of the circle must be equidistance from $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_1,y_1)$, and must also be equidistant from $(x_0,y_0)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$.  This gives two lines, whose intersection (if such exists) must be the center, and you can immediately determine the radius.

Answer (score 10):

Two circles can have at most two common points (they can intersect at 2 points at most). Hence they can have only one common chord.I hope this image is illuminating.

[image: Two circles with common chord]

Answer (score 6):

A circle is defined by three non-collinear points. Two chords are defined by at least three points, so by taking two chords of a circle, you take at least three points, which uniquely defines your circle.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the equations of two circles in a Cartesian Coordinate plane are given by:

$A$ ≡ {($x$,$y$) : A = $x^2$ + $y^2$ + $2gx$ + $2fy$ + $c$ = $0$}

$B$ ≡ {($x$,$y$) : B = $x^2$ + $y^2$ + $2g'x$ + $2f'y$ + $c'$ = $0$}

Consider a point ($α$,$β$)∈ $A$∩$B$. The duplet ($x$,$y$)=($α$,$β$) must satisfy both $A$ and $B$, and thus must also satisy

A-B = $2(g-g')x$ + $2(f-f')y$ + $(c-c')$ = $0$

The above represents the equation of a straight line. Thus, any point satisfying both $A$ and $B$ must also satisfy $L$ ≡ {($x$,$y$) : $A-B$ = $2(g-g')x$ + $2(f-f')y$ + $(c-c')$ = $0$
}, and thus must demarcate an intersection between $L$ and either of $A$ or $B$.

However, we know that any arbitrary line may intersect a circle at a maximum of two distinct points. Thus, the circles intersect at a maximum of two distinct points (there can be a maximum of two solutions to a system of a linear and a quadratic equation in two variables), which demarcate a single chord. Infact, $L$ represents the equation of the chord passing through the points of intersection of $A$ and $B$ ∎